# How do I sort a List<Type> by List<int>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my c# MVC project I have a list of items in that I want to sort in order of another list

```
var FruitTypes = new List<Fruit> {
    new Fruit { Id = 1, Name = "Banana"},
    new Fruit { Id = 2, Name = "Apple" },
    new Fruit { Id = 3, Name = "Orange" },
    new Fruit { Id = 4, Name = "Plum"},
    new Fruit { Id = 5, Name = "Pear" },
};

SortValues = new List<int> {5,4,3,1,2};
```

Currently my list is showing as default of fruit type.

How can I sort the Fruit list by SortValues?

Comment: Can there be duplicated Fruits? Like more then one Banana or Plum? If so, would they have to the same ID?

Comment: No the fruits cannot be duplicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unclear if you are sorting by the indexes in `SortValues` or whether `SortValues` contains corresponding `Id` values that should be joined.

In the first case:

First you have to [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) your two lists together, then you can sort the composite type that Zip generates, then select the FruitType back out.

```
IEnumerable<FruitType> sortedFruitTypes = FruitTypes
    .Zip(SortValues, (ft, idx) => new {ft, idx})
    .OrderBy(x => x.idx)
    .Select(x => x.ft);
```

However, this is simply sorting the first list by the ordering indicated in `SortValues`, ***not*** joining the ids.

In the second case, a simple join will suffice:

```
IEnumerable<FruitType> sortedFruitTypes =  SortValues
    .Join(FruitTypes, sv => sv, ft => ft.Id, (_, ft) => ft);
```

This works because `Enumerable.Join` maintains the order of the "left" hand side of the join.

Comment: Code is written from memory, but IIRC, it should be fine.

Comment: what is the underscore for?

Comment: Also FruitType is of type List, will this work for that listing type?

Comment: @Skullomania In later versions of C# it's a [discard parameter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/06/27/c-7-series-part-4-discards/), in earlier versions, it's simply a parameter called `_`. In both cases its a nod to functional programming. We're indicating that although there's a required parameter, we're not interested in the value, so we're just throwing it away.

Comment: @Skullomania yes, this code was written with the knowledge that both sequences are lists.

Comment: I am trying this code out, it is saying that FruitTypes does not contain a definition of .Zip

Comment: @Skullomania : `Zip` is an extension method provided by Linq-to-Objects. Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file to bring it in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168860/discussion-between-skullomania-and-spender).

Answer (score 1):

While there is almost certainly a more LINQ-y way, if you tend towards verbosity, you could accomplish this with an iterator function. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<Fruit> SortFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> unordered, IEnumerable<int> sortValues)
{
    foreach (var value in sortValues)
        yield return unordered.Single(f => f.Id == value);
}
```

I like that it's explicit about what it's doing. You may consider throwing an exception when the number of items in each list is different, or maybe you just don't return an item if there is no sort value for it. You'll have to decide what the behaviour should be for "missing" values in either collection is. I think that having to handle these scenarios is a good reason to put it all in a single method this way, instead of a longer LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

**Time complexity:O(n) + TM of Linq.**

1. Declare list of fruits to store **result**.
2. **Iterate** through each fruit type.
3. Use Linq **FirstOrDefault** to get element by sorted value.

   ```
       List<int> SortValues = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 1, 2 };
       List<Fruit> result = new List<Fruit>();
       foreach (var element in SortValues)
       {
           Fruit f = FruitTypes.FirstOrDefault(fruitElement => fruitElement.Id == element);
           result.Add(f);
       }
   ```

Implementation: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zXoEef)

Comment: This is simply an inefficient join. You could speed it up by making an `ILookup` over `FruitTypes` (`FruitTypes.ToLookup(ft=>ft.Id)`)... but now you're starting to look an awful lot like the internal implementation of `Enumerable.Join`.

Comment: I haven't tried `ToLookup`, certainly I will try with it and will update my answer.

Comment: ToLookup is a hidden gem. Definitely worth learning about. It's a bit like `ToDictionary`, but with multiple values per key. Allows for O(1) lookup.